# Self executing function inside of another

Tags: javascript

```
'use strict';
$(function () {

 var MyValues = []; //--> for Data
  function myArraysValues() {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/AdminLte/TestArray',
          type: 'Get',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { test: 'Client_Call' },

          success: function (data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                  MyValues.push(data[i]);
              }
          },
          error: function (data) {
              alert("error");
          },
      })
      return MyValues;
  }

});
//alert(MyValues);
var salesChartData = {

    labels: MyLabels,
    datasets: [
        {
        label: "Erledigt",
        fillColor: "rgb(0, 102, 0)",
        strokeColor: "rgb(0, 102, 0)",
        pointColor: "rgb(0, 102, 0)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#66ff33",
        pointHighlightFill: "#66ff33",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgb((0, 102, 0)",
        data: MyValues
        },
```

Here's my code. How could the myArraysValues() function be executed automatically? 
It is meant for the ChartJS (SalesChart). 
When add an alert(MyValues), it works, if i get ride of it, it won't
Thanks

Comment: Asynchronous code works in a little bit different way

Comment: Just before the closing `}`, call the function: `$(function() { function myFunc() { ... }  myFunc();`   not sure the problem here.

Comment: What do you mean by "executed automatically"?  Where are you even *trying* to execute it?  Nowhere do you invoke that function.

Comment: @David I think that *is* the question.   Don't quote me on that though!

Comment: @David  self-executing myArraysValues() after a Page load

Comment: @badiiboukalane: Then just invoke it.  `myArraysValues();`  Are you really just asking how to *invoke a function*?

Comment: If i add these too lines, it works well. i'am new to JS and i want to understand how to do it properly
- MyValues= myArraysValues()
 - alert(MyValues);

Comment: @badiiboukalane: That's another problem entirely, and one which is addressed in detail by the linked question.  `myArraysValues` doesn't actually return anything meaningful in this code.  You have to respond to asynchronous code in callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by execute automatically, If you meant to execute it when the page loads, you can invoke your custom code/method in the document `ready` event. But make sure to to execute the code to render your chart **inside the ajax success handler** because data from your asynchronous call will be available inside that and you can safely access that.

```
$(function () {

    getDataFromServerAndRenderChart();  

});

function getDataFromServerAndRenderChart()
{
    $.ajax({
          url: '/AdminLte/TestArray',
          type: 'Get',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { test: 'Client_Call' },

          success: function (data) {
              var myValues=[];
              for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                  myValues.push(data[i]);
              }
              // use myValues array to initialize the chart HERE
          }
      })
}
```

Also, looks like you hard coded to execute your loop to run 8 times. I hope the data coming from server is an array with minimum 8 items so that your code won't crash.

Comment: It won't crash. It works actually only if i call the "MyValues" in an alert after the function itself.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. So use it in the success event(when the response is available).